# KVM Live Migration- VM is already active

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, live-migration

I'm trying to perform a live migration from one KVM host to another, both SLES12SP5, share the same subnet.

```
'kvm_one' hosts the server 'login01'.
'kvm_two' hosts no servers.
```

Executing the following command:

```
kvm_one:~# virsh migrate --live --persistent --undefinesource --verbose --copy-storage-all login01 qemu+ssh://kvm_two.domain.com/system
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Password: 
error: Hook script execution failed: internal error: Child process (LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu login01 prepare begin -) unexpected exit status 1: 

ERROR: VM 'login01' is already active on another KVM host!

    --> Command:    virsh autostart --disable login01
```

'login01' is not active on another KVM host, I tried to disable autostart, but it doesn't seem to be related.

Anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is coming from a [*hook script*](https://libvirt.org/hooks.html), not from libvirt itself. So it is a script that you or another admin added to the hypervisor.

The script called when libvirt tries to migrate a VM (and also start/stop a VM) is `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu`. If the script exits with an error, migration is aborted. Check this script to find out why it failed.

Comment: Thank you very much.